# How do I plot ordered categorical data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, categorical-data

I possess categorical data in a dataframe that correspond to the x-axis and the y-axis of a plot, and where these categories are ordered (e.g. a<b<c<d). However, after failing to find a similar example on Stack Overflow on how to plot said data as I have done below, I assigned ordered numbers to the categories (e.g. a,b,c,d,e were indexed by 4,5,6,7,8) and plotted the following graph

[image]

using the following lines of code:

```
    fig=plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df3["LCST"],df3["LCST.1"])

lims = [
    np.min([ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim()]),  # min of both axes
    np.max([ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim()]),  # max of both axes
]

plt.plot(lims, lims, 'k-', alpha=0.75, zorder=0)
plt.xlabel('Actual', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Estimated', fontsize=18)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim(lims)
ax.set_ylim(lims)
```

The issue is that this plot is not particularly informative and I would prefer to actually have the actual categories "a,b,c,d,..." on the axis, as opposed to the mere numbers (besides the half numbers in the axis are misleading, as they do not correspond to any categories). I tried doing the same exercise without converting the categories to numbers first, but of course the ordering was all off. Sure! I have come across many posts concerning ordering categorical data, but for some reason these are not particularly fruitful for my particular case. How can this be done? My Data is of the following format (note below is just for the sake of an example and it does not correspond to the graph plotted above):

[image]

where, say, I want to produce the same graph as above, only with the categories as the axis, such that CCC+ < B < A < A+. Any help would very much be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: We don't have your data frame, so its really hard to help you.  In general categories will appear in the order they are supplied, so sort your data frame as you would like the ticks ti show up and then plot it.